# Why does Anaconda have two site-packages libraries?

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, choropleth, miniconda

> C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs\plotly-3.1.1-py36h28b3542_0\Lib\site-packages\plotly
>
> C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly

What is the difference between these?
my code tries to pull from the second location but doesnt find things.

for example, it will tell me my module 'plotly.figure_factory' has no attribute 'create_choropleth' or something

so I transferred the files from the first location to the second one and it found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pkgs directory is somewhere to place the package downloaded and unzipped. So it is a full and complete scripts/project documents.

Actually, the second one should have the file you want if you installed the package properly. I think maybe there are some problems during installing or you just install it into some sub-environment of miniconda instead of the global environment of miniconda. So there will be some left packages which are downloaded and unzipped but not installed.

You could also copy and paste the file from the first location to the second one by yourself. If you could import properly, it should be ok.

Comment: That’s what I had to do. Hmm, well thanks for answering!